# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B in bathroom/kitchen environment

Tags: pi-3

I am investigating an idea for a little project where I want to run a Raspberry Pi in the bathroom/kitchen.

I'm looking into getting a Raspberry Pi case and touch screen, and will need microphone and speakers.

There's a couple of questions I have regarding this.

First of all, is there a waterproof/water resistant case/touchscreen for the raspberry pi. I can't seem to find that specifically says its water resistant, but I'm not planning on running under water, so it only potentially going to get affected by steam. I found https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01M0AT5O5/ref=ox_sc_act_title_3?smid=A07590992ZJ1D7QSMML32&psc=1 as a case to use, but not sure if this will survive steamy rooms.

The other problem, is if it is in the bathroom, I won't have a wall socket I can use to plug in the raspberry pi. Is there a battery power pack that can be used to power to power the raspberry pi. It would need to be powered permanently as the project would involve an always listening microphone input. So I'm looking for something that can power it enough that it would be able to keep the Pi running/listening and only require maybe charging every couple of days (obviously the longer the power packs lasts the better).

Is what I am wanting to do possible?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/pipecam-low-cost-underwater-camera/ (other projects take place in space, I bet your kitchen is not such a harsh environment, give it a try)

Comment: search for `emergency phone backup battery` on google. these are perfect for powering pis. just make sure it can supply at least 2A and has enough storage capacity(mah).

Comment: Hi @Boardy, there are a couple of things with your question. It isn't only one question. At least it can be split into two complete different questions: _"Is there waterproof/water resistant case/touchscreen?"_ and _"Is there a battery power pack that can be used to power the raspberry pi?"_ So you should make two questions on this site. But the first one is asking for specific purchasing recommendations we usually do not handle and the second one is a project you will find many answers on the internet. Please have a look at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Especially since you want to inlcude a battery, I suggest you get a bigger case without any pre-made openings, and only make the openings you will need. This way you will have plenty of space to arrange your components, and limit the possible steam intake to a minimum.

For example, I have once used a case similar to this one:

[image]